# Problems related with spin buttons

Tags: python, application-development, gtk3, glade

So, I have an important problem related with spin buttons in Python/GTK3. I'm trying to create a spin button in my project, Virtuam, and it seems to work... but with a bug which blocks the +/- toogles.

[image: Without clicking]

[image: Clicking]

Also, strangely, I can manually change the spin box value... :/

[image: With the value changed]

I've installed it in a virtual machine, and it haves the same problem.

[image: Running from Lubuntu in a VM]

It worked well before, and if I try to remove the source and download a commit which worked, I still have problems. What should I do? Is it a GTK bug, or it's my fault? In the last case, what's wrong: the script (vui.py) or the interface (assistant.glade)?

You can download the latest commit at **lp:virtuam/trunk**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the increment. You can do that by using the `set_increments()` method of the spinbutton:

```
spinbutton.set_increments(1.00, 5.00)
```

That will set it to increment by 1 when left clicking the -/+ and by 5 when middle clicking the -/+.

Comment: P.S.: Why then it worked before? :/

Answer (score 0):

- Click the spin button and go to its properties menu on the right
- There you can see a property called adjustment just below spin button's name.
  [image: spin Button Properties]
- To the right of the adjustments there is a button with "...", click it
- On the dialogue box that appear click new
- A new item adjustments would have appeared on the widgets 
  [image]
- Click it and its properties you can adjust step increment, max value, min value etc. etc.

Comment: I already did that before having the bug. Thanks anyway!